# typedef template class error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, typedef

I have the following class

```
template < int rows, int columns >
class Matrix
{
    //stuff
};
```

I am doing the following:

```
typedef Matrix<4,4> Matrix3D;
```

However I am getting errors when I declare the following in another class:

```
class Transform3D
{
public:
    Matrix3D matrix;
        //some other stuff
};
```

The errors I see are:

```
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'matrix'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

all these are at line 7 which is:

```
    Matrix3D matrix;
```

This is in VS 2010. What could be the issue?

Comment: oh that poor semicolon at the end :)

Comment: sorry! copied it wrong into stackoverflow, it exists in my VS code

Comment: Are `Matrix` and its `typdef` visible to `class Transform3D` ?

Comment: Yes. the class Matrix and the class Transform3D have the #include "stdafx.h" at the top of their files. The typedef Matrix<4,4> Matrix3D; is inside file stdafx.h

Comment: Also, I dont get errors if I do this same deceleration in my main instead of this class.

Comment: Do you have special compilation options or project properties?

Comment: I am not sure...I just started a new c++ project in VS 2010 and said ok, so it might just be using default options. Is there a way to check this?

Comment: Can you clean the build and then build it again?

Comment: Nope, still get the same error.

Comment: Solved it, thanks to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870162/why-isnt-this-typedef-working. I was typedefing too early (before the class was declared). Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your explanation I assume the following setup:

**stdafx.h**

```
// ..
typedef Matrix<4,4> Matrix3D; 
// ..
```

**Matrix.h**

```
template < int rows, int columns > class Matrix { /*...*/ };
```

**Transform.h**

```
class Transform3d { Matrix3D matrix; /*...*/ };
```

**Transform.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

If this is the case, the class Transform3D doesn't seem the definition of Matrix template, (I would expect that the typedef in stdafx.h to generate a compilation error, but I am not very familiar with precompiled headers in Visual Studio).

You should #include file Matrix.h in file Transform.h and move the typedef from stdafx.h in Transform.h. Or... you should include Matrix.h in stdafx.h, but I would do that only if you that header file is stable enough (to ensure you still take advantage of precompiled headers).

My prefered way:

**stdafx.h**

```
// ..
// typedef Matrix<4,4> Matrix3D; -- removed from here
// ..
```

**Matrix.h**

```
template < int rows, int columns > class Matrix { /*...*/ };
```

**Transform.h**

```
#include "Matrix.h"

typedef Matrix<4,4> Matrix3D; 

class Transform3d { Matrix3D matrix; /*...*/ };
```

Comment: Yup, I did something similar (I put it after the Matrix class in Matrix.h) and it works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I have created project with only one file and it did compile

```
template < int rows, int columns >
class Matrix
{
   //stuff
};

typedef Matrix<4,4> Matrix3D; 

class Transform3D
{
public:
     Matrix3D matrix;
     //some other stuff
};

void main()
{
}
```

Thus, I think the problem is related to the usage of precompiled headers. Can you tell more about how your files are organized?

Comment: each class has its own header file and a cpp file, where the class is defined in the header, and the class functions are defined in the respective cpp file. all of these files have the #include "stdafx.h" only. The stdafx.h contains the includes for each class's header file and also contains the typedef Matrix<4,4> Matrix3D; at the end of the file

Comment: Solved it, thanks to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870162/why-isnt-this-typedef-working. I was typedefing too early (before the class was declared). Thanks for the help :)